# Setting System Properties for the maven-surefire-plugin via CLI

Tags: maven, testing, maven-surefire-plugin

I am currently working on a use-case where I have to set a system property for the maven-surefire-plugin via command line. I've tried to use the `systemPropertiesFile` property but it seems like my build doesn't pick up the properties in the file . Here's the syntax that I've tried:

```
mvn install -DsystemPropertiesFile=<path-to-file>
```

I'm using Maven 3.0.5 for this. Setting the same property via the POM file works fine, but unfortunately that is not a solution I can use. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`systemPropertiesFile` is not exposed as a user property, so if you don't want to change pom.xml you could use [`argLine`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#argLine):

```
mvn install -DargLine="-DmyProperty=abc -DotherPoperty=def"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I should've seen that earlier. This overwrites the jacoco {{argline}} settings though. Guess we'll have to use jacoco:prepare and late property evaluation in the surefire-plugin, to make this work. Unfortunately, this also requires changing the project's POM file.